# Why binding doesn't work in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have Kendo UI Calendar with Angularjs and everytime i select a date i call the "onChangeData" function:

```
<div kendo-calendar="cal1" k-options="thingsOptions" k-rebind="events" ></div>
```

And in the AngularJs controller:

```
var onChangeData = function()
{
    var value = this.value();
    $scope.scopeTest = "Test";
}

$scope.thingsOptions = {
    value: today,
    change: onChangeData,
    dates: $scope.events,
    month: {
        content: $("#redDays").html(),
        empty: "X"
    }
};
```

In the html page i have:

```
<h4 class="form-control-static text-info">{{scopeTest}}</h4>
```

Why when i select a date and the function onChangeData is called, the scopeTest isn't binded in the view html page?
What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it might be because the change is happening outside the angualar digest cycle try `$scope.scopeTest = "Test"; $scope.$apply()`

Comment: It works!! I must study the digest cycle. Thanks

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is kendo calendar calls the change handler out side of the angular digest cycle... angular watches does not react to changes made outside the digest cycle till the next cycle... so the solution can be to manually call the [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) method of [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

```
var onChangeData = function () {
    var value = this.value();
    $scope.scopeTest = "Test";
    $scope.$apply()
}
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem with kendoGrid in the past and this was the reason.